# Flex-grow doesn't have the same behavior when a content is present

Tags: html, css

I have three boxes in a container. I applied `display: flex`, and I set `flex-grow: 1;` on children. Everything was fine until I put some text into a child when the box got bigger. How to make the children to remain o a same width even if I put some content into them?

```css
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.page-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
  
}
.column{
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex-grow: 1;
    margin: 20px 10px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </header>

    <body>
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <div class="column">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="column"></div>
            <div class="column"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="img"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `flex-basis: 0` to your .column element. No matter how many columns you end up using, `flex-basis: 0`  will always make each of your columns be of equal width.

```
.column {
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 20px 10px;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
html, body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.page-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    display: flex;
  
}
.column{
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 33.33%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    </header>

    <body>
        <div class="page-wrapper">
            <div class="column">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="column"></div>
            <div class="column"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="img"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Try this code.

Comment: ok, but if for example you have some margin between flex elements is not so simple to calculate the width.

Comment: It should work. Try giving margin between flex elements.